# Word - printing booklet

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

In previous versions of Word, it was very simple to print a booklet by changing the settings in printer preferences to 2-sided, then click the book icon.  You then got exactly what it said on the tin.

Word 365 seems to have disabled this functionality as, whenever I try, it forces the **document** to become landscape.  This is wrong as it has to be miniature portrait, but **Printed** in a landscape way, exactly like a book if you open the spine flat.

I can get round it meantime by putting it into PDF, that has a "booklet" button in the print box, but I would like to cut this unnecessary step out if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this change seems to have been by design. Microsoft recommends setting up the document for booklet printing from the outset, and explains how [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-booklet-or-book-in-word-dfd94694-fa4f-4c71-a1c7-737c31539e4a).